# Is it correct to use "that" in "the man that saved the girl" or should it be "the man who saved the girl"?

Tags: grammaticality, relative-pronouns

> 1. Can you help me find the man **who** saved the girl?
> 2. Can you help me find the man **that** saved the girl?

The teacher did not use "that" in this case when she corrected the exercise, so I thought it's incorrect.

Is it correct to use "that" instead of "who" in this case?

Comment: Please [edit] your posts to add details or make clarifications (not the comments). See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips and examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "that" as a relative pronoun for a human being is not nearly so common as "who" and "whom." Ngram shows "that" is used only 20% as frequently as "who." It is slightly more common to use "that" than "whom." The frequency with which "that" is used, however, shows that such use is idiomatic.

I would usually use "that" instead of "whom" in speech or informal writing and would usually use "who" rather than "that" in both speech and writing. But I suspect that set of elections is mere personal preference rather than a rule.